# VBA How to display value of cell adjacent from another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to display the maximum demand and the month associated with that demand. The month column is column A and the demand is column E. I'm pretty sure my issue lies in how I'm addressing MonthOf_Demand but can't seem to figure this out my self. Any hints/tips/methods are extremely appreciated!

This is my coding so far:

```
Sub MonthHighestDemand()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MonthOf_Demand As Date
Set ws = Sheets("DATA")

MonthOf_Demand = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4)
Max_Demand = WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("E"))


MsgBox "The maximum demand is " & Max_Demand & " which occurs at " &  MonthOf_Demand

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use ActiveCell if you avoid it, it represents where the cursor is in the sheet and the user may not do things the way you expect. Consider using a range instead.

Comment: It also looks like you're computing the Max_Demand and showing the user which month it occurred, but you code finds the month first with no reference to the Max_Demand. I would calculate the Max_Demand first and then use a vlookup to find the month. If you definitely need the first occurrence the data will need to be sorted as well.

Comment: @RichardCrossley How would I implement VLookup in order to display the max demand (column E) while showing the related date (column A)?  I added Dim sRes as a String. Was thinking something like this but can't seem to figure it out:
   
Max_Demand = WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("E"))
sRes = Application.VLookup(Max_Demand, shData.Range("a1", "e1"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the code below. Although I mentioned VLookup in my comment, index/match works better because vlookup can only search the first column in a range and return values from the range. Using the Index & Match combination allows the result to be returned from anywhere. My apologies for the confusion.

The code below works as follows:

- Find the last row of data
- Find the max demand from range E2 to Elast_row
- The value of max demand is a Double, this wasn't apparent from the question
- Use the max demand as an argument to Match to find the row of range E2 to Elast_row on which it is located
- Use the row number as an argument to Index to find the month from range A2 to Alast_row.

I've added "Option Explicit" as that's generally a good idea and finds undeclared variables.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MonthHighestDemand()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Last_Row As Long
Dim Max_Demand As Double
Dim RowOf_Demand As Long
Dim MonthOf_Demand As Date

Set ws = Sheets("DATA")
Last_Row = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

' =INDEX(A2:A<last_row>,MATCH(MAX(E2:E<last_row>),E2:E<last_row>, 0))
Max_Demand = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("E2:E" & Last_Row))
RowOf_Demand = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Max_Demand, ws.Range("E2:E" & Last_Row), 0)
MonthOf_Demand = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws.Range("A2:A" & Last_Row), RowOf_Demand)

MsgBox "The maximum demand is " & Max_Demand & " which occurs at " & MonthOf_Demand

End Sub
```

I have assumed the data is positioned as shown in the attached picture.

- Column headers
- Months in column A
- Demand in column E

Using the following sample data

[image: Sample Data]

Running the subroutine yields the following result.

[image: Result of subroutine]

Comment: Wow, this is extremely helpful! It runs properly but gives me the incorrect month with the demand which is not the maximum. Odd that it worked on yours but not mine? o.O

Comment: I have the data oriented that way as well with other columns of data between them, if that has anything to do with this.

Comment: Do you have any column names or some such, my code assumes you don't. Can you paste some sample data in your question. That would help me reproduce your environment and help you further

Comment: Oh, of course! My bad, probably should have posted the columns with their respective data/names in the first place. Here is half of the data of the spreadsheet with respective column titles: https://imgur.com/a/zme7lOG

Comment: @PaperCupStraw Updated using your sample data. Column headings now taken into account along with floating point numbers. Apologies for the delay, family issues that required me to travel.

Comment: No worries,hope all is well. Thank you for this, I came up with nearly the same solution!